# Status Bar moves down UIImageView in iphone 4 iOS 7

Tags: swift, ios7, statusbar, iphone-4

I'm developing an app for iOS 7 using Swift. My app has a login view in wich I use an UIImageView to set a background image. Everything works fine but when I test my app on an iphone 4 the status bar moves down the UIIMageView a little, as you can see in this image:

[image]

The UIImageView is positioned at y = 0(Align top to superview) and with and align center x equals to 0. The view mode is scale to fill.
The UIViewController that handles this view just control if the phone has internet connection and don't do anything with the UIImageView.

I tried to set the status bar hidden in the info settings of my project, also in the info.plist file and in the appdelegate when the app is launching by using the method setStatusBarHidden, but nothing works.
How I should deal with with the misplacement of the image, I don't care if I have to hide or not the status bar?

Comment: The status bar is not in the wrong place; the image is. Do you want to deal with the misplacement of the image, or do you want to know how to hide the status bar?

Comment: I want to deal with the misplacement of the image, I don't care if I have to hide or not the status bar.

Comment: So how is this view controller and its view handled? How is the image view positioned? What is its content mode for the image? Revise your question to give actual information about what you are doing.

Comment: ok thanks for the feedback, I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: Also the `clipsToBounds` of the image view could be important, because the image can stick out beyond the image view if you're not careful.